# how to solve this integral that arises from keplers equation

Tags: integration

How do I solve the indefinite integral given below

[image]

thanks!

Comment: Well, it seems pretty straight-forward to me. Write down $V(r)$ in the integral, change variable $t=\frac1r$ and then try to recover an integrand similar to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ by completing the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\phi=\int \frac{M dr}{r\sqrt{2Er^2+2kr-M^2}}$$
Let $r=1/x$, then
$$\phi=-\int \frac{M dx}{\sqrt{2E+2kx-M^2x^2}}=-\int \frac{M dx}{\sqrt{A^2-(Mx-k)^2}}, A^2=2E+k^2/M^2$$
$$\implies \phi=-\sin ^{-1} \frac{Mx-k}{A}+B, x=1/r$$